# How to have a simple manual ECS deployment in CodePipeline / CodeDeploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline

Basically I would like to have a simple manual deploy step that's not directly linked to a build. For use cases, when using containers, I wouldn't like to perform a build separately per environment (eg: once my build puts an image tag in ECR, I would like to deploy that to any number of environments).

Now, I know in CodePipeline I can have a number of actions and I can precede them with manual approval.

The problem with that is that should I not want to perform the last manually approved deploy, subsequent executions will pile on - the pipeline execution doesn't complete and what comes next will just have to wait. I can set a timeout, for sure, but there are moments when 20 builds come in fast and I don't know which one of them I may want to deploy to which environment (they generally all go to some QA/staging, but some need to manually deployed to a particular dev-related environment or even to production).

Manually updating task definitions all around in ECS is tedious.
I have a solution where I can manually patch a task definition using awscli and yq but is there a way to have a simple pipeline with one step that takes a manual input (aka image tag) and either uses an ECS deploy step (the only place where you can provide a clean straight patch json to patch the task definition) or uses my yq script to deploy?